# What can I do to recursively output the following shape with python

Tags: python

I want to implement the following shape recursively in Python, how can I do it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

At present, I am still trying. One idea is to use coordinates. The top layer is at the origin, the left is the x-axis -1, the y-axis -1, the right is the x-axis +1, the y-axis -1, and so on. Then start traversing the second picture, first put the third layer on the left on the x-axis, and so on. However, it should be noted that each time the x-axis is traversed, -2 is required, because not doing so will cause the places where the left and right sides meet to overlap.

Now, I have below code:

```
def tree():
# for i in range(n):
#     pass
x = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
y = [2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
x_min = min(x)
x = [item - x_min for item in x]
print_tree(x, y)


def print_tree(x, y):
# size=len(x)*len(y)
for i in range(max(y) + 1):
    new = ""
    for j in range(max(x) + 1):
        if (j, i) in zip(x, y):
            new += '*'
        else:
            new += ' '
    print(new)


tree()
```

Comment: I will suggest you first check how many triangles you have to draw at each level so if k==6 then do k//3=2 so that means you have to draw 2 levels on each level you have to draw that many traingles

Comment: See [ask]. SO is not for a discussion. Do your own programming, and post a [mre] and debugging details if you confronted a problem. That said, try with 2D array(lists in a list) of characters and drawing two sub trees recursively, just like traversing a binary tree.